# Can't parse JSON to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this HTML box:

```
<span>Select depatament</span><span>
    <select id="department" onchange="EnableSlaveSelectBox(this)" data-slaveelaments='{"a": 1, "b": "2"}'>
       <option selected disabled>-Select-</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Event onchange() implementation:

```
function EnableSlaveSelectBox(element) {
    var d = $('#department').data('slaveelaments');
    alert($.parseJSON(d));
}
```

But when onchange() event is fired I get on this row:

```
alert($.parseJSON(d));
```

This error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
>
> return JSON.parse( data + "" );

Any idea why I get error above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't need use `parseJSON`, because `d` is `Object`,

```
function EnableSlaveSelectBox(element) {
    var d = $('#department').data('slaveelaments');

    console.log(d.a);
    console.log(d.b);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7xcjvr4a/)

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array
>   (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string;
>   it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If
>   the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a
>   string.

[$.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

Answer (score 3):

Because, interestingly, jQuery seems to automatically parse the string to an object. To test this:

```
alert(d); // [object Object]
```

Or do this to see the stringified version again:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(d)); // {"a":1,"b":"2"}
```

Aside: I didn't know jQuery did that until I tested it.

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing . . . you learn something new every day.   :)  Nice feature jQuery guys!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery data() will already convert properly formatted json to array or object.

This is as documented in APi

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string.

[data() API DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/data/)